# Merging two observations

Tags: stata

I have a list of places with population, much like in the example data below:

```
sysuse census, clear
```

How can I combine (sum) only two observations to create a new observation, while maintaining the rest of the data?

In the below example I would like to combine Alabama and Alaska to create a new observation called 'Alabama & Alaska' with the sum of their populations.

With the new observation, the previous records will need to be deleted.

```
   +----------------------------+
   | state        pop           |
   |----------------------------|
1. | Alabama      3,893,888     |
2. | Alaska       401,851       |
3. | Arizona      2,718,215     |
4. | Arkansas     2,286,435     |
5. | California   23,667,902    |
   +----------------------------+

   +-----------------------------------+
   | state                 pop         |
   |-----------------------------------|
1. | Alabama & Alaska      4,295,739   |  <--Alabama & Alaska combined
2. | Arizona               2,718,215   |  <--Retain other observations and variables
3. | Arkansas              2,286,435   |     
4. | California            23,667,902  |  
   +-----------------------------------+
```

This is my original toy data example and its expected output:

```
PlaceName  Population
  Town 1      100
  Town 2      200
  Town 3      100
  Town 4      100

PlaceName             Population 
Town 1 & Town 2           300  
         Town 3           100  
         Town 4           100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it with `collapse`. As you ask, this combines two observations into one, and thus changes the dataset.

```
clear

input str6 PlaceName Population
"Town 1" 100
"Town 2" 200
"Town 3" 100
"Town 4" 100
end


replace PlaceName = "Towns 1 and 2" in 1/2 
collapse (sum) Population , by(PlaceName)

list 

     +--------------------------+
     |     PlaceName   Popula~n |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |        Town 3        100 |
  2. |        Town 4        100 |
  3. | Towns 1 and 2        300 |
     +--------------------------+
```

Comment: Note that this solution will get rid of all the other variables in your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Using your original toy example, the following works for me:

```
clear

input str6 PlaceName Population
"Town 1" 100
"Town 2" 200
"Town 3" 100
"Town 4" 100
end

generate PlaceName2 = cond(_n == 1, PlaceName + " & " + PlaceName[_n+1], PlaceName)
generate Population2 = cond(_n == 1, Population[_n+1] + Population, Population)

replace PlaceName2 = "" in 2
replace Population2 = . in 2

gsort - Population2 

list, abbreviate(12)

     +--------------------------------------------------------+
     | PlaceName   Population        PlaceName2   Population2 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    Town 1          100   Town 1 & Town 2           300 |
  2. |    Town 4          100            Town 4           100 |
  3. |    Town 3          100            Town 3           100 |
  4. |    Town 2          200                               . |
     +--------------------------------------------------------+
```